# Find all positive integers “$n$” such that each of the numbers $n+ 1$, $n+3$,$ n+7$, $n+9$, $n+13$, and $n+15$ is a prime

Tags: number-theory

I used brute force approach and found that $4$ is the only such number (I tried till $10000$). I just wanted an explanation for why this is the case.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Can you show that one of those numbers is divisible by $5$?

Comment: +1 - I was in the process of writing a more detailed explanation about this, but I think a brief hint like you provided is better.

Answer (score 0):

Find your potential numbers by expressing in general forms, i.e. all integers are:

$$\text{One of } 2k, 2k+1$$

Here $n=2k+1\to (2k+1)+1=2(k+1)$ so never prime.

While for $n=2k$, each of the six potentials are not *generally* factorisable (i.e. you can't always take a factor out of $2k+1$ or $2k+13$ like you can $2k+2=2(k+1)$
)

So, if $n$ exists, it must be even.

Then for $3$, every integer is expressible as:
$$\text{One of } 3k, 3k+1, 3k+2$$

Let's sort through these in the same fashion.

$n=3k\to (3k)+3=3(k+1)$ prime so not possible

$n=3k+2 \to (3k+2)+1=3(k+1)$ again impossible

$n=3k+1$ gives $3k+2, 3k+4, 3k+8, 3k+10, 3k+14, 3k+16$

None of these are prime, so if solutions exist they are of the form $3k+1$

Now for $5$, every integer is expressible as:

$$\text{One of } 5k, 5k+1,5k+2,5k+3,5k+4$$

$n=5k\to (5k)+5=5(k+1)$ not prime

$n=5k+1\to(5k+1)+9=5(k+2)$ not prime

$n=5k+2\to (5k+2)+3=5(k+1)$ not prime

$n=5k+3 \to(5k+3)+7=5(k+2)$ not prime

$n=5k+4 \to (5k+4)+1 =5(k+1)$ not prime.

All failed. So there is no solution, unless $k=0\implies k+1=1$, which in turn means the only potential solutions are $0,2,4$. Of these, the only one of the form $3k+1$ and $2k$ is $4$, as you found.